# Running Cardano Docker Node

Tags: cardano-cli, docker

I am working on running the Cardano Node with Docker. I Got it working (running cardano-cli version 1.27.0) but when i execute the following command `cardano-cli query tip --mainnet` I expect a block result in the era "shelley" bit it shows me I am in the "Byron" era. The epoch parameters returns 'null' instead of a value

Comment: How long did you wait before you run the `query tip` command after starting the node? Your local blockchain first needs to synchronize (download all the blocks). This happens in the order the blocks were produced and can last for several hours.

Comment: I waited about 10 seconds. After that it was loaded I think. Do I need to wait longer?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is expected. After starting the Docker container, the cardano node will start downloading the whole blockchain. Depending on your system and internet connection it can take several hours to download the whole blockchain.

While the node downloads the blockchain, you can use the `cardano-cli query tip --mainnet` command to check on the progress. You can compare the current slot of your node with the latest slot (see https://explorer.cardano.org/) to see how much of the blockchain you already downloaded.

As soon as your node has downloaded the whole blockchain you can start to create transactions etc.

Comment: This explains it all! I see the block numbers are counting up so the download is working. The next time I run my node again I only have to download the remaining blocks and not the blockchain all over again?

Comment: Depends on where you stored the blockchain. Usually it should be stored in a mounted volume that is used by the docker container and is persisted on your drive. In that case you can continue where you left off. If you stored the blockchain data inside of the container, it is probably gone. A volume is mounted by using the `-v` argument of the `docker run` command.